# Creating and Populating JSON Object with jQuery via Loops

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a JSON Object dynamically using some multiple .each() loops. I tried using .push() but I was only able to get the first "tier" of the JSON object (the first array) populated.

The JS parses through an Excel Spreadsheet (2003/XML) file and needs to output this JSON object "styles" so I can use it to generate CSS on the page(s). So basically, we save an Excel XML Spreadsheet, my JS uses AJAX to "GET" it, then parses through it extracting the styles (and the worksheets/their data). The extraction process should then "dynamically" create this JSON object to be used elsewhere in the JS file.

Here is what I need the JSON to be after the various functions and loops are complete (unless there is a better structure or a structure that makes more sense for my situation)...

```
var styles = [
  "Default": {
    "Name": "Normal",
    "Style": {
      "Alignment": {
        "Vertical": "Bottom"
      },
      "Font": {
        "Name": "Calibri",
        "Family": "Swiss",
        "Size": "11",
        "Color": "#000000"
      }
    }
  },
  "s57": {
    "Name": "Hyperlink",
    "Style": {
      "Font": {
        "Name": "Calibri",
        "Family": "Swiss",
        "Size": "11",
        "Color": "#0066CC",
        "Underline": "Single"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

**MY JS (so far)**

```
var styles = []

$(xml).find('Style').each(function(){

  var style = {}

  var id = $(this).attr('ss:ID');

  var type = $(this).children();

  type.each(function() {

    $.each(this.attributes, function() {

      if (this.specified) {
        style[this.name] = this.value;
      }

    });

  });

  styles.push(style);

  console.log(styles);

});
```

It doesn't work so well. Once I added `style[this.name] = this.value`, the console was showing a bunch of "X: Object" entries.

SO, how can I generate a JSON object "dynamically" using the .each() and $.each() loops above?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I have searched quite a bit to try to find an answer to this already. I have found bits and pieces on how to do some of this, but none that populated the object intelligently...

**EDIT:**

Here is the XML file that I am "parsing":

[.XML Victim](http://ws4301-4323.staging.nitrosell.com/data/KH-3140300109.xml)

**UPDATE:**

I'm getting closer with this:

```
// Create JSON Object "styles"
var styles = [];

$(xml).find('Style').each(function(){

  var style = {};

  var id = $(this).attr('ss:ID');
  var type = $(this).children();

  type.each(function() {

    $.each(this.attributes, function() {

      if (this.specified) {
        style[this.name] = this.value;
      }

    });

  });

  //styles[id] = style;
  styles.push(style);

});

console.log(styles);

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').append('<div class="json-output"/>');
  $('.json-output').append(JSON.stringify(styles));
});
```

**`JSON.stringify(styles)` is now outputting this with the above scripting

```
[
{
"ss:Vertical":"Bottom",
"ss:FontName":"Calibri",
"x:Family":"Swiss",
"ss:Size":"11",
"ss:Color":"#000000"
},
"ss:FontName":"Calibri",
"x:Family":"Swiss",
"ss:Size":"11",
"ss:Color":"#0066CC",
"ss:Underline":"Single"
},
{
"ss:Horizontal":"Left",
"ss:Vertical":"Center",
"ss:Indent":"1"
},    {
"ss:Vertical":"Center",
"ss:WrapText":"1",
"ss:FontName":"Calibri",
"x:Family":"Swiss",
"ss:Size":"11",
"ss:Color":"#000000",
"ss:Bold":"1"
},
{
"ss:Vertical":"Center",
"ss:WrapText":"1",
"ss:FontName":"Calibri",
"x:Family":"Swiss",
"ss:Size":"11",
"ss:Color":"#008000",
"ss:Bold":"1"
},
{
"ss:Vertical":"Center",
"ss:WrapText":"1"
},
{
"ss:Vertical":"Center",
"ss:WrapText":"1",
"ss:FontName":"Calibri",
"x:Family":"Swiss",
"ss:Size":"11",
"ss:Color":"#808080",
"ss:Bold":"1",
"ss:Pattern":"Solid"
},
{
"ss:Horizontal":"Left",
"ss:Vertical":"Bottom"
},
{
"ss:Horizontal":"Left",
"ss:Vertical":"Center",
"ss:WrapText":"1",
"ss:Format":"0"
},
{
"ss:Horizontal":"Left",
"ss:Vertical":"Center",
"ss:Indent":"1",
"ss:WrapText":"1"
}
]
...
```

Comment: That's not JSON, it's just a regular Javascript object.

Comment: Have you thrown a debugger statement in before assigning the value to see what the value is?

Comment: @Nit, so I have been told. I see '{' and '[', and I mistake it for JSON. Could you explain what would make this "JSON"? The only thing I changed from http://json.org/example was the `var styles = []' (Swapped the `{''s for a '['. I see '[ & ]' used in "JSON" tutorials. How would this be reworked to be "JSON"?

Comment: @Daved Where in the script should I try that? (I have used a bunch of console.log() lines all over the file. Everything is fine up until `style[this.name] = this.value`. I got that little gem from another post similar to what I need. I just put it in the $.each() loop and integrated my own stuff (that reads the element's attributes).

Comment: @Nit: I think you might be wrong with that explanation. JSON is what he has above. As described by: http://json.org/ it's the object notation. Though JavaScript Object Notation is a way to originally represent "objects" in JavaScript, it's a standardized, language independent approach. When you reduce it to a string, you have a JSON string. Also refer to the example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON

Comment: @derekmx271 as for the debugger, I would put it right before you assign the value to the property. Right after your this.specified conditional.

Comment: Sorry guys, I tried to make a jsFiddle for this, but it was giving me a hard time with the XML file. So no dice...

Comment: @Daved what he has above is a JavaScript array literal. JSON is a string (or if the contents of the file started at the opening bracket and ended at the closing bracket, which would effectively be a string in usage.) The `var styles =` is what makes it a literal and not JSON.

Comment: ^ This is why I was getting funky logs in the console.

Comment: "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma)."

Comment: @Mathletics Yeah, true and thanks for pointing out my error. I tend to use the terms interchangeably, notably wrong, however. I overlooked the part where JSON is defined as a "text format." It's similar, but more a subset of Object Literal Notation. "The more you know, the more you know you don't know."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is

```
  var root = $(xml),
      styles = {},
      all = root.find('Style');

  all.each(function(index, item){
    var self = $(this),
        id = self.attr('ss:ID'),
        type = self.children(),
        style = {};

    styles[id] = style;

    type.each(function(index, item){
      var attributes = item.attributes;
      if (attributes.length){
        style[ item.nodeName ] = {};
        for (var i = 0, l = attributes.length; i < l; i++){
          var attribute = attributes[i],
              attrName = attribute.nodeName;

          if (attrName.indexOf(':') > -1){
            attrName = attrName.split(':')[1];
          }
          style[ item.nodeName ][ attrName ] = attribute.value;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

It will return an object as you describe (*although correct as your target variable is wrong because it is an array but has the structure of an object*)

Comment: Nice. I will play around with this too... It looks completely different from what I cam up with finally... I am updating my answer as we speak :) Thank you for this. I think your script is more optimized than mine...

Comment: I marked this as the answer, because it provides exactly what I asked for originally. You sir, are a rock star! This works great! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting the XML file. Instead of using this.name, reference this.localName to get the non-XML namespaced name - the actual node name. That will return an array of Objects with the styles defined in them. Additionally, since you are using an array, you won't be able to set the name/ID of the style. You need to change "styles" to an object and you can set the name/ID the same way you do with each style.

**EDIT**: *Updated with my full code as I left something out that might have really helped you.*

Try:

```
$(function () {
    $.get('/StackTest.xml', function (xml) {  // i had it locally saved in my sandbox
        var styles = {};

        $(xml).find('Style').each(function () {
            var style = {};
            var id = $(this).attr('ss:ID');
            var type = $(this).children();

            type.each(function () {
                $.each(this.attributes, function () {
                    if (this.specified) {
                        style[this.localName] = this.value;
                    }
                });
            });
            styles[id] = style;
        });
        console.log(styles);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(styles)); // see what it looks like as string - notice no array.
    });
});
```

Comment: Sweet, gonna give this a shot! Will post back... Thanks!

Comment: This outputs the same thing as my original script... I guess I am unsure how to insert values into different "tiers" of the object. The `this.name` and `this.value` are outputting the correct values. Oddly, the `JSON.stringify(styles)` is outputting '[]', not what I was expecting (which was a JSON-looking string with '{' and '['.

Comment: I updated my OP with some changes that seem to have gotten me a step closer... Maybe it can shed some light on what I can do to get the desired outcome? Thanks for your help btw...

Comment: NP. Read your other answer and comments. Realized I left a crucial part out for you. I edited my post so you could see what I did. jQuery.get() is a shorthand way of loading like your jQuery.ajax example.

Answer (score 0):

**So here is what I ended up with...**

It allow me to reference things like `styles['s57'].FontName` *(the font for all cells with the s57 style for example)*.

```
// Get Excel Spreadsheet (2003/XML Only!)
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: '/data/KH-3140300109.xml',
  dataType: "xml",
  success: function(xml) {
    console.log('%cgetExcel() was successful!', 'color:green; font-weight:bold;');
    createStyles(xml);
  },
  error: function(){
    console.error('getData() was unsuccessful');
  }
});

function createStyles(xml) {

  // Create JSON object "styles"
  var styles = {}

  $(xml).find('Style').each(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('ss:ID');
    var name = $(this).attr('ss:Name');
    var type = $(this).children();

    // Create JSON object "style"
    var style = {};

    // Identify the style
    styles[id] = style;

    // Log its name
    style['Name'] = name;

    // Add various styles to that style
    type.each(function() {

      // Loop through each style-type and log it's values
      $.each(this.attributes, function() {

        // If it exists... Log it!
        if (this.specified) {
          style[stripPrefix(this.name)] = this.value;
        }

      });

    });;

  });

  console.log('Moment of truth... ' + styles['s57'].FontName);

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').append('<div class="json-output"/>');
    $('.json-output').append(JSON.stringify(styles));
  });

}
```

**Here is what it outputs (JSON- or whatever this is...)**

```
{
  "Default":{
    "Name":"Normal",
    "Vertical":"Bottom",
    "FontName":"Calibri",
    "Family":"Swiss",
    "Size":"11",
    "Color":"#000000"
  },
  "s57":{
    "Name":"Hyperlink",
    "FontName":"Calibri",
    "Family":"Swiss",
    "Size":"11",
    "Color":"#0066CC",
    "Underline":"Single"
  },
  "s58":{
    "Horizontal":"Left",
    "Vertical":"Center",
    "Indent":"1"
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: I decided against the '[' which like everyone says- makes the whole thing an object. I also removed a tier from the output as well. Not as a compromise, but because it wasn't necessary for what I wanted (which was the ability to reference these values with `styles['s57'].FontName` and the like :)

Comment: I guess I should have also elaborated on the test I did. I was using jQuery.get() to load the XML. I will update my answer with the full code so you can see what I was doing. Sorry about that.